# Every sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a monotonic subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I have trouble with this kind of infinite construction in topology. Can someone check my proof is sound?

Let $s$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $s$ has a monotonic subsequence.

There are two cases. If $s$ is unbounded, it is easy. Without loss of generality, suppose $s$ is unbounded above. Choose a point $p_0$. For every $p_i$, there is some larger point $p_{i+1}$.

If $s$ is bounded, let $I$ be a closed interval containing all points in $s$. Then $I$ is compact and $s$ has a convergent subsequence $s^\prime$ which converges to $L$.

This is where I am not entirely sure of myself.

Let $\varepsilon_0$ be any positive number. Choose a point $p_0$ within a radius of $\epsilon_0$ of $L$. Then take $\varepsilon_1$ to be a number smaller than $\varepsilon_0$ and choose a point $p1$ within $\varepsilon_1$. Repeat this to generate a convergent sequence $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots$.

Separate this sequence into $p_{i_0}, p_{i_1}, p_{i_2}, \dots$ of points less than $L$ and $p_{j_0}, p_{j_1}, p_{j_2}, \dots$ of points greater than $L$. It might be possible for one of these two sequences to be finite, but since $p_0, p_1, p_2, \dots$ was infinite, one of these two must also be infinite. Choose one which is infinite. It will be monotonic (either increasing or decreasing, depending on which was chosen).

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056291/unconventional-but-instructive-proofs-of-basic-theorems-of-calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must choose $\varepsilon_1$ to be smaller than $|p_0-L|$ as well as $\varepsilon_0$. And you must choose $p_i$ to be not equal to $L$. (If this last condition is impossible to satisfy, then there are an infinite number of terms equal to $L$, which themselves form a monotonic subsequence.)

Answer (score 5):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in some linearly ordered set $(X,<)$.

Call $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a *peak* of the sequence if for all $m > n$ we have $x_n > x_m$, i.e. $x_n$ is larger than all subsequent terms of the sequence.

Case 1: There are infinitely many peaks: suppose $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < \ldots$ are infinitely many peaks of the sequence. Then by definition of a peak, $x_{n_1}, x_{n_2}, \ldots$ is a monotonically decreasing subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Case 2: There are only finitely many peaks. So there is some index $N$ that is the last peak. Then define $n_1 = N+1$. Then as $x_{n_1}$ is not a peak, there is some $n_2 > n_1$ such that $x_{n_2} \ge x_{n_1}$. Using recursion, we pick $n_{k+1} > n_k$ for all $k$, such that $x_{n_{k+1}} \ge x_{n_k}$, which is possible as $x_{n_k}$ is not a peak. This defines a increasing subsequence of $(x_n)$.

Alternatively, we apply the [infinite Ramsey theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Infinite_Ramsey_theorem) using the two colours on $[\mathbb{N}]^2$ where $\{n,m\}$ has colour 0 iff $x_{\min(n,m)} \le x_{\max(n,m)}$ and 1 otherwise. A homogeneous subset of $\mathbb{N}$ defines a monotonic sequence.

This works in all ordered spaces, and the topology of $\mathbb{R}$ has nothing to do with it. In fact, this is often a lemma in the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem that every bounded sequence of reals has a convergent subsequence (so using this very theorem 
in the proof of the simpler result seems circular, or overkill, or both).

Comment: Shouldn't you get an increasing sequence in Case 2?

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this is not a response to my request for proof verification.

Comment: @Tac-Tics this fact is not topological so I wanted to give a non-topological proof.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Taking a second look at your proof, I like it, but I feel like you got the direction of monotocity flipped in the two cases. The subsequent peaks must get smaller and smaller, so Case 1 should be decreasing. And Dejan mentioned Case 2 should be increasing, and while you said you had edited it, it doesn't appear it was changed. 

Thanks again for your response. I am revisiting this problem after a few days, and I think this proof is especially memorable.

Comment: Thanks. It's the "standard" proof of this fact, AFAIK. I did indeed invert the directions; it's ok now I think.

Answer (score 1):

As written, your choice of $p_0$ might b a lot closer to $L$ than $\varepsilon_1$ so you can'tknow that $p_1$ is larger than $p_0$ (if we assume - without loss of generality- that both are smaller). - It should be easy to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work: Consider a sequence $p_0, p_1, …$ made by zipping $1/n$ and $1/2^n$ – still converging to zero (and only from above), but not monotonically.

You can fix this by working with *rings* instead of *balls*.

Take a limit point $L$ of the sequence $a_1, a_2, …$. You may assume that it has no constant subsequences. So either you will find an infinitiude of its points in every neighbourhood of $L$ and above $L$ or you will find an infinitude of its points in every neighbourhood of $L$ and below $L$. Without loss of generality, assume the latter. Define
$$R_n(L) = \{x ∈ ℝ;~1/2^{n+1} ≤ d(L,x) < 1/2^n\}.$$
Set $ν = 1$, run through $n ∈ ℕ$ and whenever there is some $a_k$ (with $k > k_{ν-1}$) in $R_n$ and below $L$, pick the first one and remember its index $k$ as $k_ν$, increase $ν$ by $1$ and move on to the next $n$. As there are infinitely many $a_k$ in each neighbourhood of $L$ and below $L$ you will have to remember infinitely many $k_ν$, so $(a_{k_ν})$ will be a monotically increasing subsequence of $(a_k)$.

Comment: I don't get this. What is $\nu$? Are you remembering all such $k$ for a given $n$, or just the first? In either case, your construction doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @TonyK I get you criticism. I’m experimenting with different writing styles. I hope it’s clearer now. The argument should work. (Although I see a little gap. Let me fix this as well.)

Comment: Yes, that's clearer. Still, there are gaps. (i) Do you also require $k > k_{\nu-1}$ when you look for $a_k$? (ii) You only want to remember the _first_ such $k$ for a given $n$, right? (iii) The special case where $a_k=L$ for all sufficiently large $k$ is not covered.

Comment: @TonyK Why should it matter whether I take the first index $k$ for a given $n$ or not?

Comment: You want to take them _all_? That doesn't work.

Comment: @TonyK No, just any one of them, of course. But for that, you can use choice or pick the first one – why does it matter?

Comment: So after "increase $\nu$ by 1", you should say "and proceed to the next $n$", or something. This is not clear from your text.

Comment: @TonyK Okay, thanks. As I said, I’m experimenting with writing styles. I’m glad for the feedback: Thank you. I hope it’s okay now. If you still think the answer needs improvement we should probably move on to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19652/discussion-between-k-stm-and-tonyk).

Comment: It looks OK now.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose wlog that the points $p_{i_0}, p_{i_1}, ...$ strictly less than $L$ are infinitely many and converges to $L$. Then you can build up this sequence. $a_0 = p_{i_0}$, $a_n \in (a_{n-1}, L)$ (of course taking $a_k$ in increasing order with respect to the indexes of $p_i$ sequence). This new sequence should work.