# Proving that every sequence has either an increasing or decreasing subsequence without Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

Can we prove that every bounded sequence has either an increasing or decreasing (or both) subsequence (without first proving the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem)?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1056385/44121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can refer to [Theorem 3.4.7 on Page 80](https://sciencemathematicseducation.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/0471433314realanalysis4.pdf).

Given a sequence $(x_n)$, we can define $x_m$ is a peak if $x_m\ge x_n$ for all $n\ge m$. Then we separate the discussion into two cases, that is, $(x_n)$ has infinite many peaks (hence a decreasing subsequence) or $(x_n)$ has finite many peaks (hence an increasing subsequence).