# In any set of 9 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ a convex pentagon exists

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, combinatorial-geometry

> In any set of 9 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with no triple of points on the same line a convex pentagon exists.

My attempt:
I suppose I need to consider some convex hulls.
If the convex hull has $\geq 5$ points, just take it.
Else consider convex hull of the points inside. Here I don't understand how to finish the "bruteforce".

Comment: What if all these points are arranged on the same line? Does that count as convex pentagon?

Comment: Yes, forgot to add that there are no 3 points on the same line.

Comment: Can you prove the milder claim that at a convex quadrilateral exists?

Comment: Yes, I can prove that in the set of 5 points a convex quadrilateral exists.

Comment: Okay, you can do sort-of the same thing, but broken into a few different cases depending on ($x$) the number of vertices of the convex hull, ($y$) the number of vertices of the convex hull of the points inside, and ($z$) the number of vertices inside the latter.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what we are supposed to do in any of those cases to proved the desired?

Answer (score 2):

Erdos&co solved [the happy ending problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_ending_problem) by considering the slopes of the sides of the convex envelope and applying the [Erdos-Szekeres/Dilworth's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056291/unconventional-but-instructive-proofs-of-basic-theorems-of-calculus/1056385#1056385): every sequence with $n^2+1$ elements has a monotonic subsequence with $n+1$ elements.

Comment: I didn't understand: which objects form a sequence?

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, they only showed that for each $n$-gon there must be a least $m$ such that $m$ points in general position always have an $n$-gon among them. Finding specific least values of $m$ is harder; in particular, the case $n = 5$ was apparently first published in 1970, 35 years later.

Comment: @MeesdeVries: that is true, I should have said *"Erdos&co. opened the main road to the solution through the following technique"*.

Comment: Okay, I know about this problem, but I think that my case should be proven in the easier way.

Comment: @sooobus: I don't think so, but with nowadays computer super-powers the case $m=5$ is easy to crack by brute force, since the space of configurations is not *that* large.