# If $\{a_0, a_1, a_2, ...\}$ has no limit point does this mean $|a_n| \rightarrow \infty?$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading about meromorphic functions and it stated that a function that is meromorphic has a set $\{a_0, a_1, a_2, ...\}$ with poles at those points which have no limit point. My question is, if this set is infinite, is it true that $|a_n| \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty?$

Comment: If $|a_n| \not\rightarrow \infty$ then the given sequence would contain an infinite bounded subsequence, which in turn would have at least one limit point.

Comment: The question doesn't make a lot of sense the way it is now... you seem to be assuming that the set of poles comes with/is an an enumeration. But it is not - it is a mere set without any natural kind of ordering, *and not a sequence*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. By the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, any bounded sequence has a converging subsequence. For a nice combinatorial proof of this classical result, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1056291/unconventional-but-instructive-proofs-of-basic-theorems-of-calculus).

Answer (score 2):

The wording is a little confusing, at least for me. I suppose you meant to say that since a meromorphic function only has isolated poles, it can't be that if it has infinite poles which all of them are bounded, since then this infinite set of poles has a limit point, which cannot be.

Thus the answer is yes: $\;|a_n|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty\;$